# Porque mi v-for rompe el estilo de mi plantilla? Vuejs, Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, vuex

tengo un slider `owl-carousel`,

```
<div class="bg-secondary bg-size-cover mb-grid-gutter" 
     style="background-image: url(img/home/electronics/hero-main-bg.jpg);">
    <div class="owl-carousel" 
          data-owl-carousel="{ &quot;nav&quot;: true, &quot;dots&quot;: false, &quot;loop&quot;: true, &quot;autoHeight&quot;: true, &quot;autoplay&quot;: true, &quot;autoplayTimeout&quot;: 5500 }">
            <div class="row align-items-center " v-for="item in 5">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

al cual le hago un recorrido hasta 5 veces y funciona correctamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si al v-for recorro un array que viene desde mi controlador de laravel pasa esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que intento hacer es simplemente esto `v-for="item in items"`, 
Como dije anteriormente `items` viene desde una respuesta de mi servidor, que se carga correctamente, pero por alguna razon no renderiza correctamente, y lo unico que hago es reemplazar el `5` por `items`
Probe inicializar mi array de esta forma:

```
items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

y funciona, pero no puedo utilizarlo asi por que el slider debe ser dinamico y si no inicializo mi array con la cantidad que viene desde el controlador el diseño tambien se rompe.
No tengo idea de que esta pasando, ya estoy 2 días por el, disculpen por las imagenes pero no se me ocurrio otra forma mas simple de explicar mi problema,

ACTUALIZACION

```
<div class="owl-stage-outer owl-height">
     <div class="owl-stage">
          <div class="owl-item cloned">
               <div class="row align-items-center py-5">
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>  
</div>
```

en la consola aparece estos 3 divs que envuelven al div al cual le hago el v-for.

Comment: Fijate en las vistas renderizas con y sin el v-for. Vas a ver que estas repitiendo cosas (como divs) que no deberian estar dentro del v-for.. si mostras esas partes, tal vez podamos ayudarte.

Comment: pero cuando hago el v-for="item in 5" funciona correctamente..  lo unico que cambio es el 5 por un array, todo el codigo ya lo publique.

Comment: porque, item in 5 no es nada, entonces no hace un v-for ;).. es mas, ese v-for se debe estar quejando que no hay un key definido. Vos estas seguro que anda? o solo parece que anda? no tenes errores en la consola? apreta f12 y fijate si vue no se queja de muchas cosas... de donde venga el array no importa.. podrias simplemente escribir numeros, para verificar que relamente ves lo que queres ver...

Comment: no tengo ningun error en la consola, tambien probe ´ v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"' ´, que me da el mismo resultado. esto es realmente frustrante

Comment: pero si uso de esta forma funciona: ´ v-for="(item, index) in 5" :key="index"' ´

Comment: y cuando sale todo "roto", el html resultante es correcto? porque justamente el problema es ese html resultante...

Comment: Cuando se imprime correctamente se genera dos divs que envuelven al div al que tiene el v-for. tratare de compartir el div que genera

Comment: y cuando no lo hace correctamente, cuantos div imprime?

Comment: y imprime directamente uno detras de otro el div al cual le hago el v-for, sin embargo si miras el codigo que subir ahora, se repite dependiendo de cuantas veces se recorra

Answer (score 1):

Despues de 2 dias encontre la solucion, que en realidad es muy simple, mi array se cargaba despues del slider y este ultimo ya no se volvia a actualizar.. por lo que destruir y llamar de nuevo al slider fue la solucion

```
$(".carousels").owlCarousel('destroy');
    $(".carousels").owlCarousel({
        autoWidth:true,
        loop:true,
    });
```